# Hypernym for time workers spend

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a single or two word which will represent following words

> Absence,
>
> Holiday,
>
> Overtime,
>
> TimeInLieu

Comment: EL&U policy does not permit questions (or answers to questions) about how to name things, because there can be no "right" answer (even if there can be "good" answers), and voting boils down to a popularity contest. So unfortunately this question will be closed. But just do you're not left empty-handed, you might want to start your search on the [Wikipedia article for *time clocks*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_clock).

Comment: @DanBron thanks, I modified my question, is this any better now ? thanks

Comment: That is better, yes. So as it stands, are you looking for a word which is a hypernym for all those other words, as *vehicle* or *conveyance* are for *car*, *truck*, *boat*, *plane*, *rocket*, etc? A sort of category all the words fit into? (And did you look into the "time clock" article? I think it offered some promising leads.)

Comment: @DanBron Yes and I am looking into it - seems helpful, but real Trouble is , Overtime & TimeInLieu are more like "Time Management" and Absence & Holiday are hard to put in a single container in words hierarchy... I may end up using most suitable generic word for all of these words like Resource

Comment: @Mathematics My company had, in addition, nonfixed holiday, paid day off, vacation, short-term leave, long-term leave, and probably some I've forgotten.  The generic term for them was "time not worked."

Comment: @deadrat 'Time not worked' doesn't usually include 'overtime'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, missed that.  If it's any category of "time," then there would hardly be a hypernym beyond "category."  If it's any time except regular 9-5 work hours, then the company used "nonstandard" time.  (This was before "flextime" and the like.)  But that sounds like daylight savings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a hypernym for concepts not really closely enough related to make it at all likely that there will be one.

Answer (score 1):

The items you listed (or abbreviations for them) can be called **Pay Codes**

Each amount of time a worker works has to be coded with a valid Pay Code, to indicate what type of time it was, so that pay can be calculated accordingly, and available sick, vacation or personal time adjusted accordingly.

An essential Pay Code that you did not list is

- **Regular Time**

Others might include

- Sick Time
- Paid Leave
- Jury Duty
- Personal Hours

There may be additional Pay Codes, depending on the company's work and pay policies.

see, for example 
https://www.ecu.edu/cs-admin/humanresources/customcf/Kronos/ECU_Appendix%20_Glossary%20of%20Terms.pdf

Answer (score 0):

**Time logged.**

What will make this work is to add "time worked" to the OP's list.